# Get annotation parameter with IntelliJ IDEA structural search

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm trying to generate named queries for JPA entities using table name specified in `@Table` annotation with structural search and replace.

So to start I'm trying the following template:

```
@Table($param$ = $value$)
public class $clazz$
```

I have many classes like:

```
@Table(name = "Some Table")
public class SomeClass
```

and if I replace with the same template, it correctly grabs that $param$ is `name`, $clazz$ is correct class name, but $value$ is empty.

I'm using IDEA 12 build 128.101

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same experience, can't narrow the search using $value$ variable for annotation element value.

Comment: @IgorSpasic, vote up, if you have same experience!

Comment: I confirm that this issue exists.

Comment: Denis, I'm sure that this is a bug of IDEA. Because of other structure string constants replacement works fine. I think it must be reported to the JetBrains support team.

Comment: @Andremoniy: thanks. I've contacted JetBrains support about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this issue was [already reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65982) a long time ago, but no one seems to care about it. Try voting up the ticket in youtrack.

Comment: yeah, it was this bug. they've opened it now.